# Bootstrap navbar overflowing

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

When I remove the navbar height the overflowing is fixed but I want it to be 5rems. The navbar's content comes out of the 5rem nav bar and merges with the main body content and whatever I do it doesn't help.

[image: navbar content overflowing]

I tried removing the height and overflow control but nothing worked.

Here's the navbar code:

```
<header>
  <nav class="sticky-top navbar navbar-expand-md bg-body-light border-bottom ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/listings"
        ><b><i class="fa-brands fa-airbnb"></i> WanderLust</b></a
      >
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/listings">Explore</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="/listings/new">Airbnb Your Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <form class="d-flex" role="search">
            <input
              class="form-control me-2"
              id="search-in"
              placeholder="Search destinations"
              aria-label="Search"
            />
            <button class="btn" id="search-btn" type="submit">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>Search
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <% if (!currUser){ %>
          <a class="nav-link" href="/signup"><b>Sign Up</b></a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="/login"><b>Log In</b></a>
          <% } %> <% if (currUser){ %>
          <a class="nav-link" href="/logout"><b>Log Out</b></a>
          <% } %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Here's the boilerplate code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>WanderLust</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
    <link
      href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v3.2.0/mapbox-gl.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v3.2.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/rating.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <%- include('../includes/navbar.ejs') %> <%-include('../includes/flash.ejs')
    %>

    <div class="container"><%- body %></div>

    <%- include('../includes/footer.ejs') %>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I'm adding the css to boilerplate code the navbar starts to overflow.

Here's the css code:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
}

/* Navbar */
.navbar {
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: white;
 
}

.fa-airbnb {
  color: #ff5a5f;
}

.nav-link {
  color: black !important;
}

/* Seach Bar */
#search-btn {
  background-color: #ff5a5f;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
}
#search-btn i {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

#search-in {
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 0.5rem 3rem 0.5rem 3rem;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
}


/* Navbar */

.navbar {
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: white;
}

.fa-airbnb {
  color: #ff5a5f;
}

.nav-link {
  color: black !important;
}


/* Seach Bar */

#search-btn {
  background-color: #ff5a5f;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
}

#search-btn i {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

#search-in {
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 0.5rem 3rem 0.5rem 3rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" / -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v3.2.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v3.2.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/rating.css" / -->
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="sticky-top navbar navbar-expand-md bg-body-light border-bottom ">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/listings"><b><i class="fa-brands fa-airbnb"></i> WanderLust</b></a
      >
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/listings">Explore</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="/listings/new">Airbnb Your Home</a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" id="search-in" placeholder="Search destinations" aria-label="Search" />
          <button class="btn" id="search-btn" type="submit">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>Search
            </button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/signup"><b>Sign Up</b></a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="/login"><b>Log In</b></a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="/logout"><b>Log Out</b></a>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <%- body %>
  </div>

  <%- include('../includes/footer.ejs') %>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You should present your problem _before_ a wall of code, and you should combine all your code into a demo snippet using the editor. See [ask]. Also, it's bad practice to override fundamental library classes like `container` in your stylesheet. For one thing, Bootstrap offers all the [flexbox classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink) you need to accomplish the same. For another, any future developer is going to be thrown off by this global override. Use Bootstrap's classes on individual elements or create a custom class to use in addition to the core class.

Comment: I've added an image up there please check it out.

Comment: I didn't ask for an image. We can't debug images. Have you looked at the editor to see what it offers so my request makes sense? It seems like you're avoiding doing so for some reason. It's not difficult.

Comment: To help you out I added a demo at the end. If it shows your problem, 1) remove all the other code in the post, and 2) uncheck 'Hide by default' in the snippet configuration. Then we have something to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly changing it, which messes with the responsiveness of the site, add top and bottom padding to the navigation bar. This will increase the height of the `<nav>`. To do it, just add `pt-4 pb-4` classes to your `<nav>`. (Refer to this to see how it works- [Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/#notation)) like-

`<nav class="sticky-top pt-4 pb-4 navbar navbar-expand-md bg-body-light border-bottom ">`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
}


/* Navbar */

.navbar {
  background-color: white;
}

.fa-airbnb {
  color: #ff5a5f;
}

.nav-link {
  color: black !important;
}


/* Seach Bar */

#search-btn {
  background-color: #ff5a5f;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
}

#search-btn i {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

#search-in {
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 0.5rem 3rem 0.5rem 3rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" / -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v3.2.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v3.2.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/rating.css" / -->
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="sticky-top pt-4 pb-4 navbar navbar-expand-md bg-body-light border-bottom ">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/listings"><b><i class="fa-brands fa-airbnb"></i> WanderLust</b></a
      >
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/listings">Explore</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="/listings/new">Airbnb Your Home</a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" id="search-in" placeholder="Search destinations" aria-label="Search" />
          <button class="btn" id="search-btn" type="submit">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>Search
            </button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/signup"><b>Sign Up</b></a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="/login"><b>Log In</b></a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="/logout"><b>Log Out</b></a>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <%- body %>
  </div>

  <%- include('../includes/footer.ejs') %>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```